# strange npe in jQuery method

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery method which **works fine if I am on a page where there are elements found** which have class `.singlePaneOfGlassBlock`.

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
        //I only want this to run on IE for now, but the content 
        //is prepared to run on other browsers too
        if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
            var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock"), oldName = elem
                    .attr("oncontextmenu"), fn = String;

            //IE returns function instead of string so let's try to take the string
            //in the right way
            if (typeof oldName == "function") {
                oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value,
                        fn = Function;
            }
            //do the replace
            oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                    'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
            //change oncontextmenu with the new value
            jQuery.each(elem, function() {
                this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
            })
        }
    }
```

But it failes with this error:

```
`'undefined' is null or not an object`
```

on the line where it tries to do the replace if I am on other pages where those type of elements are missing...

I have add a checking to see if it's null or if it contains that string before doing the replace, but it still fails:

```
if (jQuery(oldName).length || oldName.indexOf("Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup") != -1) {
        oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
        jQuery.each(elem, function() {
            this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
        })
    }
```

Can you give me a solution?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: when I'm asking a solution I'm just asking on how to correct this method to not run when that type of elements are not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Re your updated code in the question:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock"), oldName = elem
                .attr("oncontextmenu"), fn = String;

        if (typeof oldName == "function") {
            oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value,
                    fn = Function;
        }

        // ====> This is where the bug is, you're assuming you have
        //       a string at this point, but you don't necessarily,
        //       because if there is no match at all, `attr` will
        //       return `undefined` or `null` (I forget which).
        //do the replace
        oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
        //change oncontextmenu with the new value
        jQuery.each(elem, function() {
            this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
        })
    }
}
```

to fix:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock"), oldName = elem
                .attr("oncontextmenu"), fn = String;

        if (typeof oldName == "function") {
            oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value,
                    fn = Function;
        }

        // ====> Add this `if`:
        if (oldName) {
            //do the replace
            oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                    'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
            //change oncontextmenu with the new value
            jQuery.each(elem, function() {
                this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Original answer**:

It seems to me you're missing some braces (at least):

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
    var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock"), oldName = elem
            .attr("oncontextmenu"), fn = String;
    if (typeof oldName == "function") { // <=== Added { here
        oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value,
                fn = Function;

        oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
        jQuery.each(elem, function() {
            this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
        })
    } // <=== Added } here
}
}
```

Here's the above with the indentation corrected:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock"), oldName = elem
                .attr("oncontextmenu"), fn = String;
        if (typeof oldName == "function") { // <=== Added { here
            oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value,
                    fn = Function;

            oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                    'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
            jQuery.each(elem, function() {
                this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
            })
        } // <=== Added } here
    }
}
```

Here's your **original** with the indentation corrected:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock"), oldName = elem
                .attr("oncontextmenu"), fn = String;
        if (typeof oldName == "function")
            oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value,
                    fn = Function;

        // Note how these statements are NOT protected by the `if`
        // above, and so if `oldName` is `undefined` (as opposed to
        // being a String or Function.
        oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
        jQuery.each(elem, function() {
            this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
        })
    }
}
```

Or it may be that you're missing an `else` clause and probably a further defensive `if`:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock"), oldName = elem
                .attr("oncontextmenu"), fn = String;
        if (typeof oldName == "function") {
            oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value,
                    fn = Function;
        }
        else {    
            oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                    'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
        }
        if (oldName) {
            jQuery.each(elem, function() {
                this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But it's really hard to say, I can't quite follow the logic. The function path part of it doesn't seem to change anything, but the string path part does...

Comment: thanks, I've added the braces but on correct location for my case. Howerer, npe error is not because of this..

Comment: @Cristian, @Alnitak: I've updated a bit. @Cristian: If you step back and describe what you're actually trying to do (probably as a separate question), I think there's very likely a better way to approach it.

Comment: @Cristian: Re your updated code: You're still assuming you get back a `Function` or a `String`; see my updated answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - year I've just updated the code with explanations...basically it works perfectly on the pages where there are elements with that class but fails on pages where aren't (it's ok to "fail", to not do anything, but I do not want to give me error in IE, so I want to not run that code when those elements are missing)

Comment: @Cristian: Yes, you said originally it worked fine when they were there. Again, see the check I added to your code, it should address the issue.

Comment: better to check whether the original selector ever matched, and ignore the entire code block if it didn't.

Comment: @Cristian: LOL glad that helped. Looking at it again, I'd probably move that check up above the function check, not that it makes much difference. Best,

Answer (score 2):

> Can you give me a solution?

I'm not sure - for starters please format your code so that it's clearer what it's supposed to do.  It *looks* like you may have a missing pair of curly brackets after the `if` condition.

At the very least, *don't* use comma-separated expressions to achieve two assignments - put that block in curly brackets and split out the two assignments properly.  Then the code logic should become clearer.

In any event, since your problem only occurs when that class doesn't exist on the page, that should be your *first* test:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock");

        if (elem.length > 0) {   // new test here!

            var oldName = elem.attr("oncontextmenu");
            var fn = String;

            if (typeof oldName == "function") {
                oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value;
                fn = Function;
            }

            //do the replace
            oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup',
                                       'contextMenuPopupUpdated');

            //change oncontextmenu with the new value
            jQuery.each(elem, function() {
                this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I stuck to an absolutely minimalist change approach, but I sure prefer this code to the original. (You didn't change *much*, but it reads much more cleanly.)

Comment: thanks - I hate comma separated declarations, they're far too error prone, and they're hard to read too.  Having the test here avoids any extra processing as early as possible, too!   [I've given you a +1 for effort, too...]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `jQuery(oldName).length`, why don't you just do `oldName != null`?